# When to use Scala Vector, when Scala Array?

Tags: scala

If I need an Array with multiple degrees, I can't use a Vector. But let's consider the simple case of having only one degree: When to use Scala Vector, when Scala Array?

Comment: `Vector` when you want immutability. `Array` when you want mutability.

Comment: You might enjoy this recent [blog post about scala collections](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html)

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to time and space complexity, arrays are surprisingly versatile. You might expect that arrays are slow with regard to inserts and deletes until you consider modern memory architectures. CPUs can prefetch and stream arrays straight from memory while performing linear operations on them, such as copying for an insert or delete. Most other data-structures requires expensive indirections, defeating prefetching caches.

### Immutability

Since linear access to arrays is very fast, I often (for smaller arrays) consider them as immutable and copy them on write.

### How to choose

When I consider a data-structure for a certain task, I start by analyzing the performance implemented as a simple array. Only after this first step, I weigh the benefits and penalties of existing abstractions, such as vectors. Possible benefits of other data structures might be readability, code complexity, performance at scale, opportunities for garbage collection, ease of serialization and cache coherence. Readability and code complexity are on the top of my list, and this often weighs in favor of abstract data structures such as Vectors, Lists, Streams and Maps.

### Consider GPU acceleration

When starting with arrays, I always consider the possibility of GPU execution. For example, machine learning heavily relies on vector (not to be confused with Scala vector) and matrix operations (linear algebra), which is accelerated on GPU hardware and often less memory intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a data structure is, as always, a matter of context.

First of all, you have to take into account the issue at hand, the access pattern you expect to have and the performance characteristics. The Scala documentation includes [a great comparison](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics). Both collection share the common trait of being indexed, allowing fast random access, but you'll notice some differences between the two.

A key difference between the two, as suggested in the comments, is that a `Vector` is an immutable collection, while `Array`s are mutable.

Furthermore, `Array`s in Scala are effectively mapped over Java native arrays, making it quite easy to write idiomatic Scala code that can be used by just as idiomatic Java code elsewhere.

For further details, both the [`Array`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array) and [`Vector`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector) pages of the official Scala documentation include a good description. You can learn even more in the documentation section reserved to [collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview).

Comment: Please note that these performance characteristics, based on complexity analysis, are a huge simplification of modern systems architecture. The actual performance of a data structure might (and likely is) different. 
One cannot do without measuring with micro-benchmarks and considering the CPU architecture, virtual machine behaviour and garbage collector behaviour in the relationship with a certain data structure. After doing this analysis, you will most likely come to the conclusion that complexity analysis is mostly an academic exercise.

Comment: @Dibbeke I agree with you (apart from your last consideration, which I think is too far reaching), but the question seemed to require a more high level reply. Furthermore, when using an `Array` you have to be very careful of what you do with it, because at the first implicit conversion to a `WrappedArray` you end up manipulating something very different from a native `Array`. Idiomatic Scala code will seldom take advantage of the optimizations you cited.

Comment: the last part of my comment was too much, but it was triggered by an inconvenience of the current state of affairs. It so often seems that everyone is content with doing an undergrad complexity analysis and call it a day. I refute since a complexity analysis is a nice thing to prevent the average joe from stepping on rakes, but in *modern* architectures, especially given a VM, it distracts from the essence and gives people a warm fussy feeling so they don't have to think. And yes, `WrappedArray` is a dangerous thing. We need some macro support here I guess.

Comment: I think it depends a lot on the problem at hand. Complexity analysis is an abstraction that provides engineers with a good heuristic for a good choice. Furthermore, as you mentioned in your answer, readability and code complexity should come first, especially when first iterating over a piece of code. Taking in consideration the underlying machine is important but it's a difficult task which requires many optimization that may be bespoke for a certain problem and a certain hardware. I don't see the problem in using complexity analysis as a first spearhead into the problem.

Comment: In http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html, Arrays are with the immutable collections... !?

Comment: @stefanobaghino I'm not saying that complexity analysis is useless. Thirty years ago, pipelining, branch-prediction, cache coherence, multi-core cache invalidation, JIT compilation, runtime loop-unrolling and garbage collection just did not play (as much) a role. Nowadays, with Moore's law ending, it is increasingly important to scale in, instead of up or out. When designing a time-critical algorithm, I increasingly note that complexity analysis can lead me astray and CPU/GPU architecture knowledge is key.

Comment: http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html is relevant.